# Custom scrollbar for Angular Material Table without removing table styles

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, scrollbar

How can I prevent the table style of an Angular Material table from disappearing when a custom scrollbar has a transparent background?

Currently, the following happens (I made the scrollbar extra wide to see the problem).

[image: angular material mat tab with custom scrollbar]

HTML:

```
<div class="container-list">
    <mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        <!-- ... insert basic table definition (like here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-basic)  ... -->
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

CSS (custom scrollbar):

```
.container-list {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 500px;
}
  
.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 30px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: transparent
}
  
.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: black;
}
  
.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar-button,
.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece,
.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar-corner,
.container-list::-webkit-resizer {
display: none;
}

.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
    margin-top: 450px;
}
```

Not displaying the entire scrollbar is the only solution I've found, but that's not what I want.

```
.container-list::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

It would be also important to keep the **mat-header-row fixed** (i.e., the row with column names) so that it stays in view even when scrolling. That's possible with [sticky](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sticky-rows-and-columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your Angular Material table in a container that does not have custom scrollbar styles applied:

```
<div class="container-list"> <mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
<!-- ... insert basic table definition ... --> </mat-table>
```

Create a separate container for your custom scrollbar and apply the scrollbar styles to this container:

```
<div class="custom-scrollbar-container"> <!-- Content goes here, including your Angular Material table if needed --> </div>
```

Apply the custom scrollbar styles to the .custom-scrollbar-container:

```
.custom-scrollbar-container { overflow: auto; height: 500px; }

.custom-scrollbar-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.custom-scrollbar-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}

.custom-scrollbar-container::-webkit-scrollbar-button,
.custom-scrollbar-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
.custom-scrollbar-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece,
.custom-scrollbar-container::-webkit-scrollbar-corner,
.custom-scrollbar-container::-webkit-resizer {
  display: none;
}

.custom-scrollbar-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
  margin-top: 450px;
}
```

By encapsulating the custom scrollbar styles within the .custom-scrollbar-container, you should be able to avoid interference with the styles of your Angular Material table, and the table's appearance should remain consistent even when you have a custom scrollbar with a transparent background.

Comment: Ah, good idea. But this approach doesn't work if the mat-header-row is supposed to be fixed. Any clever idea how to still ensure a fixed header?